# How to round a plane to a sphere surface

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I'm going to make the top face of cylinder to a sphere like curved surface, like a cap on top of the cylinder, I've searched a lot but everything I found is round an edge rather than round a surface

From this

[image]

To this kind of shape

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not create the domed top first from a UV sphere by deleting the lower section to get the form you want, then select the bottom ring of vertices and extrude them downward to create the cylinder section?

Comment: It is a good idea, I will try that

Comment: c If you then want to alter the curve of the top, you can select the top centre vertex and use proportional editing to alter the profile of the dome as you wish.

Comment: How to get a top center vertex, my cylinder does not have a middle vertex

Comment: use inset (i), scale down, then create additional edge loops with Ctrl B (bevel)

Comment: If you start with a UV sphere as I suggested,  press 'O' and then select the top centre vertex of the remaining part of the sphere which has created your dome. 'G'rab and move it on the Z axis using the mousewheel to alter the curve of the dome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to extrude and bevel. You can tweak the shape in the *Operator* box, or scale later on the Z axis:

[image]

[image]

You can also customize the profile of the bevel in the *Operator* box:

[image]

To illustrate John Eason solution, you can inset your top face (<kbd>i</kbd>):

[image]

Then bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) to create additional edges:

[image]

Enable *Proportional Editing (Sphere* mode) and move up the central face:

[image]

Tweak the parameters in the *Operator* box if necessary:

[image]

Comment: This seams like a good workaround, I am wondering if there is more official way to get the sphere top

Comment: you can work the other way around: create a sphere, delete its bottom half, extrude down to make the cylinder

Comment: Yeah just like @john said, I will have a try